# Saving all Drawn Objects into a Bitmap

Tags: c#, bitmap, save, picturebox

I have a Canvass (PictureBox) and Shapes, Images or Text can be drawn on it as seen int he picture below. What I want to do now is to save them all into one **BITMAP File**. I have no idea so how do I start?

[image]

PS: I'm using different Graphics object to draw each.

Comment: You should use graphics object(s) that are bound to the bitmap: `using(Grphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)...`

Comment: @TaW yeah saw that, but the project I'm working on is large now. there are a lot of graphics usage that I cannot just replace.

Comment: Well I can't comment on your project but, depending on its importance I would advise to consider reafactoring it. Ideally all drawing would be in a set of functions which all take a Graphics object as a parameter and use it for drawing. This way you are free to draw onto a control surface (your canva) or a bitmap which you an display as pbox.Image or save as you like..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a workaround, this will save the drawings in my pictureBox/Canvass.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();

            //Creates a filter fir saving the Project File
            save.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp); *.PNG|*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp; *.PNG";     
            save.DefaultExt = ".bmp";
            save.AddExtension = true;

            if (save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                using (var bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox_Canvass.Width, pictureBox_Canvass.Height))
                {
                    pictureBox_Canvass.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));
                    bmp.Save(save.FileName);
                }
            }
    }
```

**SAMPLE OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: A workaround, but the correct solution is in my comment above. This solution is needlessly tying itself to the screen, which is a disadvantage. Also : If that works you are NOT using different graphics objects but only the one from the Paint event!

Comment: Please explain, how to I get the tie just the graphics in the paint event into a bitmap, just 'that' one

Comment: I would create a list of a class 'DrawAction' (or if you need more flexibility an interface `IDrawable`) which contains all data needed to draw an item with a DrawItem(Graphics g) parameter. Then you can either loop over the items and either feed them with e.Grpahics  (maybe scaled down= in the Paint event or with a bitmap-bound graphics object (maybe scaled up) when you want to create a bitmap.`

Answer (score 1):

`Graphics` is a [*"device context"*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/device-contexts) object. It handles drawings on to `Bitmap`, but it cannot be converted back to `Bitmap`.

You can however copy the bits already painted on your window, and draw on to `Graphics`. For example:

```
protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseClick(e);

    //get the screen coordinates for this window
    var rect = this.RectangleToScreen(this.ClientRectangle);

    //copy bits from screen to bitmap
    using (var bmp = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height))
    {
        var gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        gr.CopyFromScreen(rect.Left, rect.Top, 0, 0, rect.Size);

        //save to file
        bmp.Save(@"c:\test\test.bmp");
    }
}
```

Or you can do this right after drawing in response to Windows messages, but you have to call `Graphics::Flush` to let Windows know when you have finished painting. This method assumes the target window is visible. There might be a lag between commands, or part of the window is not visible, and you don't get the desired output.

A better solution is suggested in the other answer: Create a memory bitmap and draw on to it.

If you don't want to repeat the code, you can make a function that handles all the paintings for both window's device context and memory device context:

```
public void do_all_paintings(Graphics gr)
{
    //paint something random, add all other drawings
    gr.Clear(Color.Red);
}
```

Now paint in response to Windows paint request:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);
    do_all_paintings(e.Graphics);
}
```

Use the same `do_all_paintings` function to create a file in response to a command:

```
protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseClick(e);

    var rect = this.RectangleToScreen(this.ClientRectangle);
    using (var bmp = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height))
    {
        do_all_paintings(Graphics.FromImage(bmp));
        bmp.Save(@"c:\test\test.bmp");
    }
}
```